# jQuery post calls resulting in "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES"

Tags: jquery, post

I have a page that allows the user to upload and map an CSV file.  After that is done, rows are sent through a post call to a page on a different server.  After nearly 6,00 calls (5787 to be exactly), I start getting a console error of "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES".

I've tried running the page with 100 rows in the CSV file, and it worked just fine... but when I tried a large list (over 10,000 row) it froze up.

Here's the code making the post calls:

```
for (var i = 0; i < manifestRows.length; i++)
{
    $.post('http://www.otherserver.com/subfolder/handler.php', { tblName: 'foobar', thing1: manifestRows[i][0], thing2: manifestRows[i][1], thing3: manifestRows[i][2], thing4: manifestRows[i][3], thing5: manifestRows[i][4], thing6: manifestRows[i][5], thing7: manifestRows[i][6], thing8: manifestRows[i][7], thing9: manifestRows[i][8], thing10: manifestRows[i][9], thing11: manifestRows[i][10], thing12: manifestRows[i][11], thing13: manifestRows[i][12], thing14: manifestRows[i][13], thing15: manifestRows[i][14], thing16: manifestRows[i][15], thing17: manifestRows[i][16], thing18: manifestRows[i][17] }, function(data) {
    if (data.length == 0)
    {
        var currentProcessing = $('#processingCurrent').html();
        $('#processingCurrent').html(parseInt(currentProcessing) + 1);
        var progress = Math.ceil((parseInt(currentProcessing) / manifestRows.length) * 100);
        if (progress == 99)
            progress = 100;
        progress = progress + '%'
        $("#progressBar").width(progress).html(progress);
        if (progress == '100%')
        {
            $('#processdingDiv').hide();
            $('#allDone').show();
        }
    }
    else
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Is there some code I can put in either the user end, or on the other server to prevent this Insuffiecient Resource error from occuring?

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the exact same error in an AngularJS app.  What I had to do is batch the requests.  The batch number is relative to your instance, but I used 1,000 calls at a time.

Since a lot of this happens asynchronously, I had to create two variables.  `httpRequestsExpected` should be same as batch size, depending on your code.  In mine, I just incremented it every time I called `$http.$get();` to get the exact value.

`var batchSize = 1000;`
`var httpRequestsExpected;`
`var httpRequestsMade = 0;`

Then in the http **success and error functions**, increment `httpRequestMade`.

To resolve a batch, and because http sometimes hangs, I couldn't do an exact match like:
`if(httpRequestsMade === httpRequestsExpected)`
but had to put in padding like this:
`if(httpRequestsMade >== httpRequestsExpected - (httpRequestsExpected *0.01))`

Then start the next batch, incrementing your starting pointer by `batchSize` and reset the variables. That provides a safe amount of buffering and time for the process to finish without consuming all the resources.