# Sending 100k requests to Google URL Shortener API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-url-shortener

I'm using Javascript to build a URL Shortener tool that can process about 100k URLs at a time using Google's URL Shortener API. However in testing, when it comes to something around 3k - 4k, it shows error in the console:

```
net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Here's my code:

Load all URLs into array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.data.length; i++) {
    var idx = results.data[0].indexOf('Redeem URL');
    if (i === 0) {
        continue;
    }
    requestArray.push(results.data[i][idx]);
}
```

Send the request:

```
if (requestArray.length) {
    for (var i = requestArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        makeRequest(i);
    }
}

function makeRequest(idx) {
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
        'resource': {
            'longUrl': requestArray[idx]
         }
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        if (idx === requestArray.length - 1) {
            console.log(requestArray.length);
        }
        if (response.id != null) {
            urlResults.push({
                'Redeem URL': response.longUrl,
                'Shorten Redeem URL': response.id
            });
        }
    });
}

function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', function(){});
}
window.onload = init;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You might want to do this by batch.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122506/neterr-insufficient-resources-error-when-adding-numerous-img-elements-to-dom) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161236/jquery-post-calls-resulting-in-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insufficient-r)? "*Turns out that even though it is incredibly slow to load so many images, the strange error was coming from AdBlock Plus. I disabled that chrome plugin and the errors went away*"

Comment: @majidarif I tried to use Google's Batch request, but still doesn't work :(